# 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Had the following issue when created universal app in VS 2015 and tried to use .ToShortDateString() method for DateTime in the Shared Project.
Visual Studio 2015 intellisense shows this as an error, but the application runs fine. Just wondering, is this a bug in VS or am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could always use `.toString("d")`, which does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks mate, error's gone and got the same result.

Comment: Hey, idk why, but i added questionmark, like ```dateToDisplay?.ToShortDateString```, and for gods sake, for some reason it worked. Why it doesn't result in alert...? X)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UWP apps use the [new CoreCLR](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/30/universal-windows-apps-in-net/) for compilation. The CoreCLR does not support `DateTime.ToShortDateString` at this time, and [it doesn't seem to be getting much traction](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2317) anyways. Those helper methods are bad at localization.

You can simply replace the call with `dateToDisplay.ToString("d")`.

#### Update

Looks like it got some traction! This method (along with several others) was [added back into the CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/10241). This move was done to improve parity with the APIs in Xamarin and the .Net Framework. You can read more about this decision [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/making-it-easier-to-port-to-net-core/).

Comment: Problem still exists with .forms 3.1 and VS2017. I don't use the UWP project, but also the Android project is not to compile (of cause the errors to the UWP project) - strange wise not by every attempt (seems to be an error in VS). Changed to .ToString("d") and works… (for all platforms)

Answer (score 12):

Change the code to:

```
var test = dateToDisplay.Value.toShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only an error because code analysis is told to treat this as an error. You can change this to a warning or ignore completely, but it is recommended to improve your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. Wrote this code as a sample in VS 2015 to test. Although I didn't get the error in VS 2013.