# ToShortDateString() not available?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm coding in a console app in C# and neither of the following lines of code are compiling:

```
var x = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
var y = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Please update your question with any information about the compiler errors you're getting.

Comment: maybe try adding `;` at the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265067/datetime-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-toshortdatestring-in-vs2015

Comment: are you writing a console app or a windows universal app? as the link you have provided is for a universal application

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting the `semicolon` at the end.
Think of the `;` as please, if you dont say please at the end, your code with not work, 
c# is a polite language.

```
var x = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
var y = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();

Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```